# How do you log into a 3rd party web app in a Windows Hosted Web App?

Tags: windows, facebook, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, hosted-app

I love using Facebook's messenger.com web app but don't like the Messenger Universal App for Windows.

So I thought I'd create my own Hosted Web App wrapper for messenger.com.
[The process seemed simple](https://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/CreateHWA.htm). And it was.  The app opens and loads messenger.com.

But, the second you click the Login button it kicks you out to a browser window.

Is it possible to log into a 3rd party service in a Hosted Web App?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem, only when I want to register a new account, it will open a new website using browser. I think you also don't want to use FB's web api to make your own web service?

Comment: Thanks for helping Grace! Can help me out with what you put in the package.appxmanifest file?  What is in 'Start page' on the Application tab and what entries did you make for the URI's on the 'Content URIs' tab?  Thanks!

Comment: start page: https://www.messenger.com/, Content URIs: Uri: https://www.messenger.com/, Rule: inlcude, WinRT access: All. Nothing special. My OS version is 10586.

Comment: Thanks again for helping out. The manifest doesn't allow me to simply put messenger.com for the Uri rules.  It's requiring http or https as part of the rules. What are you using exactly? Just to verify... you can log into Messenger through the app you created?  Thanks! My OS version is 1607.

Comment: Yes, my uri is`https://www.messenger.com/`, when pasted here, it is shorted。 Yes I can log into the Messenger, and I logged in and out several times.

Comment: Well... that worked!  I started from scratch again today and it worked. I did select "Hosted Web App" for the project type this time instead of following the exact directions posted.  Thanks.